# How can I sum the total Amount by each month and group them by the categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to get the total grouped by each month along with each category. I can't seem to figure out how to do both. I can get the total by each month or I can get the total by each category but how can I combine them?

[image: data]

I tried the groupby function and the grouper function.

```
        data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        data['Transaction Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Transaction Date'])
        data = data.set_index('Transaction Date')
        data.resample("M").sum()
        category = data.groupby(['Category']).sum()
```

I only get the sum with the category grouped or the month grouped but not both.
[image: resample]

[image: category]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Take time to read the following page on how to produce a good example to ask your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Don't paste pics, paste data directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
         'Transaction Date':pd.to_datetime(['09/03/2019','09/20/2019','08/25/2019',
                               '08/25/2019','08/26/2019', '06/10/2019']),
         'Amount':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'Category':list('aaabbb')
})
print (data)
  Transaction Date  Amount Category
0       2019-09-03       7        a
1       2019-09-20       8        a
2       2019-08-25       9        a
3       2019-08-25       4        b
4       2019-08-26       2        b
5       2019-06-10       3        b

df = data.set_index('Transaction Date').groupby('Category').resample("M").sum()
print (df)
                           Amount
Category Transaction Date        
a        2019-08-31             9
         2019-09-30            15
b        2019-06-30             3
         2019-07-31             0
         2019-08-31             6

data = data.set_index('Transaction Date')
df = data.groupby(['Category', pd.Grouper(freq='M')]).sum()
print (df)
                           Amount
Category Transaction Date        
a        2019-08-31             9
         2019-09-30            15
b        2019-06-30             3
         2019-08-31             6
```